# <li> problems, links are going on top of each other not side by side

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists

Hopefully you can see what the problem is, I want the links to go side by side not on top of each other?

Can you please see what the problem is on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pky7X/

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the top and bottom margins to -35px? You're effectively making their height 0 (or less) and it's making a real mess of the layout. [See here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm), for a basic example of styling a horizontal list.

Comment: That's pretty handy! thank you

Answer (score 0):

At first, you forgot the `<ul></ul>`

```
<style>
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}
li {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #ff9900;
}
</style>

<ul>
   <li><a href="../">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="../">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It still does the same thing :/

Comment: It does, but it is not valid.

Comment: I'm confused now :s i've removed the <li> and <ul> tags okay and just got the <a> tags but now my margin is spacing them apart like theirs a huge gap throuhg them and when I resixze the margin they get too close or come off the screen :/

Comment: Why have you removed the <li> and <ul> tags? You can keep them.<br/> If there is a huge gap between the <a>'s, you have to adjust their margin.<br/> I don't know, how it looks like now, without your code.

Comment: Instead of `margin: -35px 220px;`, `margin: 5px;` looks fine for the li elements and without `</br>`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First: You're missing `<ul>` around your `<li>` tags (don't think that's valid in HTML5; it wasn't before).
Second: Why even using list items and then removing the `list-style` and adding `float`?

Just use `<span>` or the `<a>` directly...

```
<a href="./">Home</a><a href="./about">About</a>
```

... and then use CSS to set their padding, style, dividers, etc.

Comment: Using `<li>` for a menu is the right thing. Actually, a menu is a list of links (menu items). So rendering it as a list is semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br />` and place `<li>` tags inside a `<ul>` like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="../">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin: -35px 220px;` from CSS and remove the `<br />` from HTML.